# Can't get named router-outlet to show up the content

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I can't get the named `router-outlet` to work in my scenario:

I have navigation bar `nav-schedule.component.html` defined like below:

```
<nav class="admin-nav navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a routerLink="schedule" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item nav-link">Test</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In my `schedule-routing.module.ts` I have the following definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavScheduleComponent, outlet: 'schedule-nav' },
  {
    path: '', component: ScheduleLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ScheduleListComponent },
      { path: 'function/:id', component: ScheduleFunctionComponent },
      { path: 'schedules/:id', component: ScheduleComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

`schedule-layout.component.html`

```
<div class="p-4">
    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet name="schedule-nav"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

My navigation bar (that I would expect to appear before the content of the main router-outlet) does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `routerLink="schedule"` but no `schedule` route. And you don't give the name of the outlet to your routerLink, how is it supposed to know where to go ?

Comment: Can you be more specific what I need to fix? How do I give the name of the outlet to my `routerLink`

Comment: `schedule` is the current context - it already pre-exists.